# Category Theory: Naturality and Notation

Tags: category-theory

I'm confused by some Category Theory notation but I give the whole question I'm interested in solving below for the sake of context.  Also, I want to verify my understanding of the proper approach to a solution assuming I can figure out this notation.

Here is the original question:

> Let $\mathcal{F}:\mathbf{CRing}\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}$ be the
>   forgetful functor mapping a commutative ring to its underlying set and
>   mapping a ring homomorphism to itself. Show that $\mathcal{F}$ is
>   represented by $\mathbf{Z}[T]$

**1.** The first part of my question is, what is $\mathbf{Z}[T]$ if $\mathbf{Z}$ is the additive group?

**2.** Now assuming I know what $\mathbf{Z}[T]$ is, in order to show that it represents $\mathcal{F}$ I just need to find a natural transformation from $\mathcal{F}$ to $\mathbf{Z}[T]$ such that an appropriate naturality square commutes, right?

Comment: $\mathbf{Z}[T]$ is the ring of polynomials in $T$, with integer coefficients. The natural transformation you want is from $\mathcal{F} \to \text{Hom}(\mathbf{Z}[T],-)$. That is, specifying a point of a ring $R$, is the same thing as specifying a ring homomorphism $\mathbf{Z}[T] \to R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that the functor $\mathcal{F}$ is *co*represented by $\mathbb{Z}[T]$, what you need in fact is a natural *isomorphism* from $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}[T],-)$ to $\mathcal{F}$.

For any category $\mathcal{C}$, any functor $\mathcal{F} : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathrm{Set}$ and any element $X \in \mathcal{C}$, there is a bijective correspondence between the set of natural transformations $\mathrm{Mor}(X,-) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ and the set $\mathcal{F}(X)$: the element of $\mathcal{F}(X)$ associated to a natural transformation $\alpha : \mathrm{Mor}(X,-) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ is defined to be $\alpha_X(\mathrm{id}_X) \in \mathcal{F}(X)$; and conversely, if you have an element $u \in \mathcal{F}(X)$, the components $\alpha_Y : \mathrm{Mor}(X,Y) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(Y)$ of the associated natural transformation $\alpha : \mathrm{Mor}(X,-) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ send a morphism $f : X \rightarrow Y$ to $\mathcal{F}(f)(u) \in \mathcal{F}(Y)$. This fact ( - and the analogous fact for *contra*variant functors $\mathcal{F} : \mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{op}} \rightarrow \mathrm{Set}$ - ) is known as the *Yoneda lemma*.

Now, in your situation, I claim that the natural transformation $\alpha : \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}[T],-) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ corresponding to the element $T \in \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{Z}[T]) = \mathbb{Z}[T]$ is a natural *iso*morphism. To show that, we have to show that for every ring $R$, the function (of sets) $\alpha_R : \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}[T],R) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(R) = R$ is bijective. But for a ring homomorphism $f : \mathbb{Z}[T] \rightarrow R$, we have $\alpha_R(f) = \mathcal{F}(f)(T) = f(T)$, so that, indeed, $\alpha_R$ is bijective. (The set of ring homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}[T] \rightarrow R$ corresponds bijectively to the set of elements of $R$, by associating to a ring homomorphism $f : \mathbb{Z}[T] \rightarrow R$ the element $f(T) \in R$.)